# Redirect from https www.domain.com to https www.domain.co.uk

Tags: redirect, plesk

I would like to ask a question. I had a domain like

```
  (https)www.domain.com
```

and i transfered the whole domain to

```
(https)www.domain.co.uk
```

but i have some seo issues. I want the

```
(https)www.domain.com/every_url
```

to redirect to

```
(https)www.domain.co.uk
```

I did it for domain.com/every_url to redirect to

```
(https)domain.co.uk
```

but if I hit an article from google that has already the https  its shows a previous server error. For hosting I use plesk with dedicated server and i used 301 permanent redirect. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Wrong platform isnt it ?

Comment: where should i post it then? lol